# Postgres 14 and pg_trgm index on primary key column make join operations super slow

Tags: postgresql, indexing, trigram

I've just upgraded my postgres instance from v11 to v14. There was an interesting problem because we have a trigram index on `order_id` column.

This new feature makes our simple join query on that column very slow. For example:

```sql
SELECT count(*) from order_rows o1 join order o2 on o1.order_id = o2.order_id
```

To solve, this problem the existing trigram index must be dropped and we cannot use `ILIKE` queries on this column. I just wonder is there anyway to tell postgres what index (in this case btree index) to use when doing the join operations?

> [Postgres 14] Allow GiST/GIN pg_trgm indexes to do equality lookups (Julien Rouhaud)

References

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-14.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgtrgm.html

Comment: Could you show the query plan both with and without the trigram index?

Comment: Is the primary key index extremely bloated?  What if you reindex it?